# How to create an array for WSDL and pass it as an argument using suds?

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, wsdl, suds

I would like to make a request. Those are parameters that are required. The problem is that I don't know how to create an array that I would be able to pass a parameter in order to make an request using suds library.

```
$dogetitemsinfo_request = array(
   'sessionHandle' => '22eb99326c6be29aa16d07d622bcfbcbee94ad54846f2f4e03_1',
   'itemsIdArray' => array(975967833, 886978949),
);
```

This is my class for making requests:

```
class OffersViewAndOptions:
      @classmethod
            def doGetItemsInfo(
                    cls,
                    sessionHandle,
                    itemsIdArray,
            ):
                global client
                client = Client('https://webapi.allegro.pl/service.php?wsdl')
                response = client.service.doGetItemsInfo(
                    sessionHandle=sessionHandle,
                    itemsIdArray=itemsIdArray,
                )
                do_get_items_info = {
                    'itId': response.item[0].item[0].itId,
                }
                return do_get_items_info
```

Here is my frist attempt to pass an array as parameter

```
array = [6688519219, 6688519219]
getitem = OffersViewAndOptions.doGetItemsInfo(session_handle_part, array)
```

Here is the response:

```
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'Element '{https://webapi.allegro.pl/service.php}itemsIdArray': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
```

Second I searched on SO for possible solutions and I found this:

```
array = client.factory.create('array')
array.item = [7554257498, 6688519219]
request.option=array
```

Here is the response:

```
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'array'
```

This documentation  may be helpful:
https://allegro.pl/webapi/documentation.php/show/id,1093